# Python/Django: I need some code to run between requests, which concept to look for?

Tags: python, django

I am trying Django for my project, which contains server-side code, which should work between requests. It should be initialized at server start, keep state, and polled sometimes between HTTP requests.

I can write own server with python http.server but it seems overkill at the moment, simple (Django built-in HTTP) server is ok for my project for now. Which is the simplest way to implement server-side code for typical Django project?

**Edit:** So I am looking for something like this:

```
# my_serverside_module.py

# keep during server lifetime
state = [] 

# called at server start
def init_module(): pass 

# called by framework 1 time per minute
def poll(): pass 

# called by myself during http request from Django code
def do_something(): pass
```

Comment: What do you mean by running between requests? That it hooks into random requests and adding more data [to the response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/)? Or [scheduled tasks](https://medium.com/@bencleary/django-scheduled-tasks-queues-part-1-62d6b6dc24f8)?

Comment: I think something like scheduled tasks. Maybe I have formulated not so clear. Code should work not between (before/after) requests, but independently from requests, so it's doing own job during server lifetime and http requests asks it for something while executed.

Comment: Then it's definitely scheduled tasks - have a look at [celery](https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/), it lets you create async tasks which you can trigger anywhere and create periodic tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

**Option 1: Server side process**

Each django app can register code to call when it is starting up via the [AppConfig's ready](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready). If you'd like to start some backend polling/computing thread and module, this is where you would do it. Keep in mind that this gets complicated **very** quickly considering (a) it's multi-process programming and (b) the many ways to handle WSGI requests (single threaded, gevent, multi-process, multi-threaded) and if you're in a distributed environment. Does consistency between hosts, process, thread, etc matter?

**Option 2: Tasks**

As another answer indicated, this is where async workers shine. Things like [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) were designed for this and integrate nicely. In my opinion, this is the **correct** way to engineer the problem.

I know this answer is kind of regurgitating the one from Chetan, but I hope it adds a little more clarity.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe resembles cron jobs or scheduled tasks.

There are multiple ways to solve this in Django. [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) is a widely-used distributed task queue that also supports [periodic tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html).

Another possibility is to use available open-source projects that can be found on Github if a simpler solution fits your needs. Examples:

- https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab
- https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron

Answer (score 1):

Django Middleware framework is what you need.

Please check the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/)

Comment: Thx, but seems it's not I am looking for. If I got well, middleware is running before/after request, but my code should work independently from requests, it should be initialized and keep it's state during server lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

In production, any Django application will run with more than one server process, so the key question here is where to keep your state and how to share it between processes.

Depending on your requirements, you might be able to keep your state in your SQL database or in a memory-backed database like Redis. In this case, you can call `init_module()` in `AppConfig.ready` and use Celerybeat or Cron for executing `poll()`, as others have suggested. Note that your `init_module()` will be called once per server process. If that is an issue, you will have to implement some kind of locking or use a Django management command that you execute separately.

If your state *must* be stored in memory as a Python data structure, a separate, single process Python server might actually be your only choice. Just look out for any scaling issues. The polling could then be implemented with a thread, but triggering it externally with Celerybeat or Cron would work too.

Answer (score -1):

## my_serverside_module.py

## keep during server lifetime

state = [] 
Ans: This can be implemented using the celery(store state in python variables) and/or redis(store state in memory i.e. in redis). You could use redis and django middleware/from views to update state using celery tasks.

## called at server start

def init_module(): pass 
Ans: This could also be implemented using celery. Or
the ready function of an app in the apps.py file of the main app in the django project.

## called by framework 1 time per minute

def poll(): pass 
Ans: as far as I know django, i never came across something like this so far. That does not mean it cant be done :P I dont know the answer to this.

But using celery you can call a function/task every minute. It wont be called by django, but it will be called every minute.

## called by myself during http request from Django code

def do_something(): pass
Ans: this is definitely the middeleware part, See middleware hooks for more info. Write a utility function and call it from middleware hooks.
Middleware hooks are useful if you want something to happen before or after the view function is called.

If you want a function to be called during the view is being processed, you can use the signals concepts in the django. You can send a signal during the view is being processed using python code.